# Drupal - Host as server and create node on request

Tags: drupal

I was wondering if it is possible to host a drupal site a request server and create nodes dynamically. For example, send a junk of data to a url (which is a Drupal site) and then the server creates a node on the drupal based on the received data.

A sample scenario would be, the user uses the mobile app to send some data to the URL, the server upon receiving will create a node on drupal which can be viewed later on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using Drupal [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module. It will provide you a standardized solution of integrating external applications with your Drupal site. An example of posting node using custom fields is provided [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1354202).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use the REST API module which does that elegantly and simply: https://www.drupal.org/project/restws